# why only one of these two equivalent queries raise ORA-22806: not an object or REF

Tags: sql, oracle

This query works.

```
WITH 
function do_something(arg varchar2) return varchar2
is
begin
    return 'fff';
end;
t (a) AS (
  SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   t
PIVOT (
  ANY_VALUE(do_something(a))
  FOR a IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

But not this query. Although it's basically the same.

```
WITH 
function do_something(
  arg varchar2
) return varchar2
is
begin
    return 'fff';
end;
t (a) AS (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd'))
)
SELECT *
  FROM t PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(do_something(a)) FOR a IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```

> [Error] Execution (42: 27): ORA-22806: not an object or REF

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a1db771517c6056033197445d6307b36)

Comment: You are probably not going to get an answer to this as it is probably a bug. There may be something in My Oracle Support (MOS) relating to it but it is a pretty obscure corner-case and, when I answered your original question relating to this and gave you the first query, I went through multiple options using `CAST` and creating user-defined types rather than built-in `VARRAY`s and nothing I did would appear to get the second query to work.

Comment: If you really want an answer then your best bet is not to ask StackOverflow but to file a ticket with Oracle support. (Even then they probably won't tell you what is wrong but would just give a patch to fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

This works when you do not call the function:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION do_something(
  arg varchar2
) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'fff';
END;
SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(COLUMN_VALUE)
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

and outputs:

> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | b | *null* | d |

This works when you put in a static value instead of the function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE('fff')
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

and outputs your expected value:

> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | fff | fff | *null* | fff |

Using the built-in function `NVL2` also works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(NVL2(COLUMN_VALUE, 'fff', NULL))
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

and outputs your expected value:

> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | fff | fff | *null* | fff |

If you call the user-defined function before the `PIVOT`:

```sql
WITH function do_something(
  arg varchar2
) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'fff';
END;
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS v,
         DO_SOMETHING(COLUMN_VALUE) AS dv
  FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
)
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(dv)
  FOR v IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

then it outputs your expected value:

> | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | fff | fff | *null* | fff |

If you call the user-defined function after the `PIVOT`:

```sql
WITH function do_something(
  arg varchar2
) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'fff';
END;
SELECT NVL2(a, DO_SOMETHING(a), NULL) AS a,
       NVL2(b, DO_SOMETHING(b), NULL) AS b,
       NVL2(c, DO_SOMETHING(c), NULL) AS c,
       NVL2(d, DO_SOMETHING(d), NULL) AS d
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(COLUMN_VALUE)
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a' AS a, 'b' AS b, 'c' AS c, 'd' AS d)
);
```

then it outputs your expected value:

> | A | B | C | D |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | fff | fff | *null* | fff |

However, calling the function inside the pivot generates the error:

```sql
WITH function do_something(
  arg varchar2
) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'fff';
END;
SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(DO_SOMETHING(COLUMN_VALUE))
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

> ```
> ORA-22806: not an object or REF
> ```

Moving the function out of the sub-query factoring clause and into the SQL scope still does not work:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION do_something(
  arg varchar2
) RETURN varchar2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'fff';
END;
/

SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(DO_SOMETHING(COLUMN_VALUE))
  FOR COLUMN_VALUE IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
);
```

> ```
> ORA-22806: not an object or REF
> ```

Neither does explicit casts and specifying identifiers:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, d
FROM   (
  SELECT CAST(COLUMN_VALUE AS VARCHAR2(1)) AS v
  FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'd')
)
PIVOT(
  ANY_VALUE(CAST(DO_SOMETHING(v) AS VARCHAR2(3)))
  FOR v IN ('a' AS a, 'b' AS b, 'c' AS c, 'd' AS d)
);
```

> ```
> ORA-22806: not an object or REF
> ```

As for your question:

> why only one of these two equivalent queries raise `ORA-22806: not an object or REF`

- It works when the data is specified using `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...` but not when using `SELECT ... FROM TABLE(...)`.
- It works when the function called is a built-in function and not a user-defined function.
- It works when the user-defined function is defined and not called.
- It works when the user-defined function is called outside of the aggregation.

Somewhere between the `VARRAY`, the user-defined function and the aggregation in the `PIVOT` clause there is a perfect storm of things that confuses the SQL engine and makes it expect either an `OBJECT` or a `REF` (to an `OBJECT`) and then raises the errror.

If you want to know "why" then you will need to ask Oracle support.

If you want to work around it then make sure that one of these occurs:

- Do not use collection data types to generate the data (get the data from a table or from `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...`).
- Do not user-defined functions inside `PIVOT`'s aggregation (either use them before or after the aggregation or use an equivalent built-in function).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=880b495fffa514a1a4cf17b9fb845c77)*